# Excel 2010 / Outlook 2010 - Changing the size(with precise numbers) of a chart exported from Excel to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-outlook-2010, charts

If I export(copy&paste) charts from Excel 2010 to Outlook 2010, I'm not presented with a "size proprieties" option when trying to resize them. Since I have multiple chart to resize for each report, I would like to know if there's a way to automate the process using a macro or to change the size using numbers instead of manually doing it. Pasting as a picture is not an option due to email size & image quality.

Comment: Check, if you resize the chart before copy and paste will you get what you want?  If so, you can make a vba macro to size down, copy, and the resize to original.  This way your clipboard has the smaller chart.